# Window Phone 7 C# pass paramters in a routedeventhandler

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to pass parameters to a function that is used in a RoutedEventHandler

```
Button start = new Button();
start.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(playSelectedAlarm_Click);

private void playSelectedAlarm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AlarmPicker.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

how do I do this? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add your parameters into the Button's [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property. Then, extract them in your event handler:

```
Button start = new Button();
start.Tag = new string[] { "param1", "param2" };
start.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(playSelectedAlarm_Click);

private void playSelectedAlarm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    //extract the parameters and cast to a `string[]`
    var myParameters = (string[])((Button)sender).Tag;
    string p1 = myParameters[0]; //value is "param1"
    string p2 = myParameters[1]; //value is "param2"


    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AlarmPicker.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

The `Tag` property expects an `object` type, so you can input an array of parameters, collection, string etc..

Answer (score 0):

Change your :

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AlarmPicker.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

to

```
var uri = "/AlarmPicker.xaml?idx=" + url + "&title=" + title);
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));
```

After that, in your `AlarmPicker.xaml.cs` add this:

```
out string m_Link = string.empty;
out string m_Title = string.empty;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("idx", out m_Link);
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("title", out m_Title);

    Console.Writeline("IDX: " + m_link);
    Console.Writeline("TITLE: " + m_Title);
}
```

It's called **when you load AlarmPicker.xaml**!
It's used to get passed values, like a query string.

hope this helps

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I need to know how to get those variables into that function so I can pass them as you have described

Comment: You can pass values using "?" and "&" syntax, like and url. In your receiver class, you need to get these values and use it as you want. See edit.